# Ways to work offline with your WordPress

Tags: migration

I want to work on my WordPress using my shared hosting space and then do a backup and upload it in my client hosting space, is that possible? I am novice and I am struggling in how get working on the website before launching it, I read about MAMP but not sure if it will do the trick, I just want to be able to work on the website and once is ready I can upload it without hassle. Can anyone help me with some tips?

Comment: MAMP is a good to use. Then, you can [move the site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) to some other server later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAMP is the quickest route to a local dev environment.

You can also use your Mac as a LAMP server without to much trouble, I found this more stable and easier to recreate server conditions than using MAMP. This is an excellent guide https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

A 3rd option is to start using Docker... 
This is my current choice as (if you use Docker on your prod server) you can recreate conditions exactly and each site can have its own config within a container

https://codeable.io/wordpress-developers-intro-docker/

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use Docker on a personal project and see how it goes, but for while I will use MAMP, or least try since it's my first time using it.